# Advice needed in how to implement the scale() function in R

Tags: r, scale, data-manipulation, centering

**Context**

As part of my studies in ecology, I am trying to stick to a quantile regression method performed in Karlsson et. al (2022) (source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.02206.pdf). As I am facing some unexpected challenges (more insights here if interested: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572277/theory-understanding-behind-quantile-regression), I am trying to reproduce as much as I can their methodology, in order to find some solutions to my problems.

Here is how I assume that their dataset has been built (+ some covariates columns that I will not take into account):

| individual | year | julian_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | y(1) | j(1) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| n | y(n) | j(n) |

Basically, 1 row = 1 bird, the year it was recorded and the day it was recorded (julian day format).

I am trying to reproduce a sentence that I first ignored because I thought it was not as a matter of importance:

> For all fitted models, year was centered around 2001.

It is the **only** information that they provide in the paper about centering the year column.

**Question**

> The scale() function, by default, subtracts the mean from each individual observation and then divides by the standard deviation. By specifying scale=FALSE, we tell R not to divide by the standard deviation.

My question is straightforward: as nothing else is specified, what is the "common use" of the scale() function? Regarding the quoted sentence, what would you think that the scale argument should be: FALSE or TRUE; and why?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think you want to use in your model `I(year - 2001)`. That will centre the year around 2001.  `scale()` will centre around the mean, which may or may not be 2001 depending on the data.  If `scale=FALSE` only centring is done.  If `scale=TRUE`, then the resulting centred variable is divided by its standard deviation.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer (if you post it, I can accept it)! I did not know about the `I()` function, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use in your model `I(year - 2001)`. That will centre the year around 2001. `scale()` will centre around the mean, which may or may not be 2001 depending on the data. If `scale=FALSE` only centring is done. If `scale=TRUE`, then the resulting centred variable is divided by its standard deviation.